# How to remove spaces from linq data in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

I have linq where data in one of column may have spaces or special character between string, for example my survey, your's survey. I need to remove this so after filtering linq should return mysurvey and yourssurvey

column I am interested to remove spaces and special character is consultation = consultation.Name

I am using C# .net core and entity framework

```
      var query = (from consultation in Context.Consultations
                     join survey in Context.Surveys on consultation.Id equals survey.ConsultationId into surveys
                     select new 
                     {
                         consultationId = consultation.Id,
                         consultation = consultation.Name,
                         surveyId = surveys.FirstOrDefault() == null? null : surveys.Select(x=>x.Id),
                         survey = surveys.FirstOrDefault() == null ? null : surveys.Select(x => x.Name),
                         subject ="survey"

                     });
```

Comment: LINQ is just a query language. It's not an ORM. Which ORM are you using and why don't you use *relations*? It's the ORM's job to generate JOINs from the relations and navigation properties. You wouldn't need to write anything more than `from cons in Context.Consultations from survey in cons.Surveys ....`

Comment: Or you could write `from survey in Context.Surveys select new { survey.Consultation.ID, survey.ID...}` etc.

Comment: i am using entity framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to remove spaces & special characters in a string use like below:

```
consultation = Regex.Replace(consultation.Name, "[^0-9A-Za-z]+", "");
```

Using namespace

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Comment: This won't work. Regex does not work as queryable, only as enumerable, which is expected, because the reqex code can't be translated into SQL. If you want to use regex, you'll first have to move the selected property inclusive the unwanted characters to the local process (AsEnumerable) before you can use a new Select containing the Reqex

Answer (score 2):

Write an extension method like this

```
public static string StripSpacesAndSpecialCharacters(this string text)
{
   var specChars = new string[] { "'", ";" }; // add more spec chars here
            var procesesedString = text.Trim();

   foreach (var spec in specChars)
   {
     procesesedString = procesesedString.Replace(spec, string.Empty);
   }
   return procesesedString;
}
```

then use it in your query like

```
var query = (from consultation in Context.Consultations
                     join survey in Context.Surveys on consultation.Id equals survey.ConsultationId into surveys
                     select new 
                     {
                         consultationId = consultation.Id,
                         consultation = consultation.Name.StripSpacesAndSpecialCharacters(),
                         surveyId = surveys.FirstOrDefault() == null? null : surveys.Select(x=>x.Id),
                         survey = surveys.FirstOrDefault() == null ? null : surveys.Select(x => x.Name),
                         subject ="survey"

                     });
```